# Apostrophe in URL becomes question mark on live server but not staging

Tags: php, url, character-encoding, kohana

I have an old site where apostrophes are allowed in URLs. This isn't ideal but it's the way it was setup, and it's worked fine until I moved to a new server. The page title is basically the "slug" in the URL, which is then used to look up the database. However, on my live server, when the title contains an apostrophe (which is displayed as an apostrophe in the URL) the apostrophe becomes a question mark when trying to process it and do the DB lookup.

I also have a staging server - the staging server and live both run centOS and php is configured the same on both as far as I can see. This apostrophe issue doesn't happen on staging but does on live. Any ideas what the reason could be? Some character encoding issue? Many thanks

EDIT: some more info...

Example URL: /about/club's-opening-times
This is showing fine in the browser URL bar.

```
 echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // outputs /about/club's-opening-times
 $page_name = end(Router::$segments); 
 echo $page_name; //club?s-opening-times
```

The same thing happens when I encode the URL - the %27 becomes ?
As you can see, I'm using a framework (kohana 2.3) library to get the URL segments, so somewhere down the line Router::segments is replacing the apostrophe with a question mark. I checked phpinfo() on live and staging and charset settings are identical. This is a strange one.

Comment: seems like a encoding problem. already tryed url_encode / url_decode?

Comment: Why not just strip out apostrophes?  It's probably bad for SEO anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you've not included charset `<meta charset="UTF-8">` above/beneath your title tag, although is hard to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your segment is not valid for Kohana route. Take a look at Kohana router class: https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Route.php

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because your PHP suhosin.server.strip setting is different between your staging and production environments.

While `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` correctly contains the single quote, Kohana uses `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` if it exists which is affected by this setting.

From https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52293&edit=1#1298061392 :

```
; When set to On the dangerous characters <>"'` are replaced with ? in
; the server variables PHP_SELF, PATH_TRANSLATED and PATH_INFO. This will 
; protect against some XSS vulnerabilities. 
suhosin.server.strip = 0
```